# Can I mint 1 NFT few time(20 times) on Solana candy machine v2?

Tags: solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I have 10 images(NFT) I need to mint each image at least 20 times(10 * 20 = 200 times) is it possible to make it in Solana with Metaplex?

If yes can you please share link to docs or another website?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You could mint them all as NFTs with the metaplex source code.

Using the candymachine V2 is one way: https://docs.metaplex.com/

When "preparing the assets" in this step: https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/preparing-assets I would just set 0-10.png to be all the same image and with whatever metadata you want.

Note: a technical aspect of this to remember is that these will be minted as NFTs so even though they have the same image they have a different mint hash. If this doesn't matter than this is a perfectly fine method to use.